# Webpack not watching subdirectories

Tags: webpack

For some reason, webpack is just watching files in my root (src) folder, that is the same folder that the webpack config file is in.

The file structure looks like this:

```
src/
    webpack.config.js
    site.js
    js/
        x.js
```

When I run `webpack --watch --progress` I can see that it picks up saves on site.js, but not for x.js.

One solution would be to put everything under src, but it would get messy.

I am running this in WSL (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) with Windows 11, and the files reside on a mounted Windows folder.

I have the following webpack config:

```
const path = require("path");
const LiveReloadPlugin = require("webpack-livereload-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const WebpackAssetsManifest = require("webpack-assets-manifest");
const ExtraWatchWebpackPlugin = require("extra-watch-webpack-plugin");

/** @type {import('webpack').Configuration} */
module.exports = (env) => {
    console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, "../src"));
    console.log(env);
    const config = {
        watchOptions: {
            followSymlinks: true,
            ignored: ['**/node_modules'],
        },
        resolve: {
            symlinks: true
        },
        mode: env.production ? "production" : "development",
        entry: {
            site: ["./site.js", "./site.scss"]
        },
        output: {
            filename: env.contenthash
                ? "[name].[contenthash].bundle.js"
                : "[name].bundle.js",
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist"),
            clean: true
        },
        plugins: [
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: env.contenthash
                    ? "[name].[contenthash].bundle.css"
                    : "[name].bundle.css",
            }),
            new WebpackAssetsManifest(),
            new ExtraWatchWebpackPlugin({
                dirs: ['./js'],
            }),],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "babel-loader",
                        options: {
                            presets: [
                                [
                                    "@babel/preset-env",
                                    { targets: { ie: "11" } },
                                ],
                            ],
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        {
                            loader: "css-loader",
                            options: {
                                url: false,
                            },
                        },
                        // "sass-loader",
                        {
                            loader: "sass-loader",
                            options: {
                                // Prefer `dart-sass`
                                implementation: require.resolve("sass"),
                            },
                        },],
                },
            ],
        },
        optimization: {
            minimize: env.production, // --env minifycss
            //minimizer: [new CssMinimizerPlugin()],
        },
    };
    // --env reload
    if (env.reload) {
        config.plugins.push(new LiveReloadPlugin({ port: 35729 }));
        // TODO - dynamically insert the reloading script tag
    }
    return config;
};
```

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try the poll option: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watchoptionspoll?

Comment: @firstlast - that did the trick! Thanks a bunch! 